# Latex Beamer: allowframebreaks with footnotes

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I created a simple latex beamer document shown below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{default}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]\frametitle{Pages}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item First page\footnote{some text}
    \end{itemize}
\newpage
    \begin{itemize}
        \item next page
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It uses a frame with the attribute **allowframebreaks**. 
There is a footnote on the first page, but it is printed on the last page of the frame sequence.
I know that this is the specified target behaviour, but is it possible to change this? I would like to have the footnote on the same slide where it is supposed to be.

Thank You.

Comment: Just put the text in two frames.

Comment: @Seamus Sure - thats the easiest way, but I would like to use the allowframebreaks attribute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The procedure of Beamer dealing with `allowframebreaks` is as follows

- collect all materials on the page (including footnotes);
- typeset materials and put them into a `\vbox` called `\beamer@framebox`;

  - at the same time, footnotes is put into a box called `\beamer@footins`;
- if `\beamer@framebox` is less than one page, shipout this box;

  - if not, `\vsplit` the box and shipout one page;
  - loop until `\beamer@framebox` is empty;
- attach `\beamer@footins` at the last page.

The lesson we learn from the preceding procedure is that we do not know which footnoteitem belongs which page. So we have three choices

- put all footnote on the last page; this is the default behavior;
- put all footnote on the first page; this is stupid;
- put all footnote on every page; this is worth a try.

**The following is the original definition**

> ```
> \def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
>   \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
>   \ifbeamer@autobreak%
>     % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
>     \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
>     \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
>     \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
>     \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
>       \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
>     \else%
>       \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
>       \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
>     \fi%
>     \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
>       \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
>       \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
>         \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
>         \else%
>           \begingroup
>             \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
>             \footnoterule%
>             \unvbox \beamer@footins%
>             \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>           \endgroup  
>         \fi%
>       \fi%
>       \beamer@exitcode%
>     }%
>   \else%
>     \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
>       \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
>       \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
>       \else%
>         \begingroup
>           \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
>           \footnoterule%
>           \unvbox \beamer@footins%
>           \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>         \endgroup 
>       \fi%
>       \beamer@exitcode}%
>     \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>   \fi%
>   }
> ```

**And we can modify the footnote part as follows**

```
\def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
  \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
  \ifbeamer@autobreak%
    % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
    \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
    \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
    \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
    \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
      \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
    \else%
      \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
      \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
    \fi%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
      \ifvoid\beamer@footins%                          MODIFIED
      \else%                                           MODIFIED
        \begingroup%                                   MODIFIED
          \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%              MODIFIED
          \footnoterule%                               MODIFIED
          \unvcopy \beamer@footins%                    MODIFIED
        \endgroup%                                     MODIFIED
      \fi%                                             MODIFIED
      \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%                         MODIFIED
          \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%  MODIFIED
      \fi%                                             MODIFIED
      \beamer@exitcode%
    }%
  \else%
    \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
      \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
      \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
      \else%
        \begingroup
          \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
          \footnoterule%
          \unvbox \beamer@footins%
          \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
        \endgroup 
      \fi%
      \beamer@exitcode}%
    \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
  \fi%
  }
```

Then we achieve the following

[image]

PS. the strange/scary jumping phenomenon is discussed here: [beamer: allowframebreaks option and vertical spacing when using lists (itemize, enumerate, ...)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357717/)