# beamer: allowframebreaks option and vertical spacing when using lists (itemize, enumerate, ...)

Tags: beamer, lists, enumerate, itemize, description

- When you use the `allowframebreaks` option in beamer then you get additional frames if the content is too high for one frame.
- The vertical spacing gets disturbed when you use a list (itemize, enumerate, description), for example, see the following animation. I used the `t` option (for **t**op alignment) for the frame.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\setlength{\mylength}{\baselineskip}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\
Text\\

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

- I thought of a solution, when I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340) question where they explain the different length in lists.
- The main idea is to check if the current frame is not the first frame of a frame continuation and add the needed vertical space.
- I thought that `\topsep` is the needed length but apparently, it is not quite right.
- It ist almost perfect but it still "dances" a little bit.
- Which additional length do I need?
- Here's the animation and the used code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
    (\insertcontinuationcount)%
    \ifnum\insertcontinuationcount>1%
    \vspace*{\topsep}%
    \else%
    %
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Frame Title}

\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\item Test
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Related

- [Align beamer slides with frame breaks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277473)
- [First slide of references in beamer starts one line further down](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275872)
- [Inconsistent slide margins in frame with allowframebreaks option in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253185)

### Definition of `\itemize` in `beamer`

In `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty` I found

```
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
      {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
      {\def\makelabel##1{%
          {%
            \hss\llap{{%
                \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
          }%
        }%
      }
  \fi%
  \beamer@cramped%
  \raggedright%
  \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
```

But I do not understand where the different kinds of spaces are defined that cause the "dancing".

### "Evil" Stuff in beamer

Motivated by the comment of @cfr I searched the `beamer` documentation for "evil" stuff -- this is what I have found (beamer guide version 3.41):

- Do not use `subsubsections`, they are **evil**.
- Never ever use the **evil** option `shrink`.
- Using this [again `shrink`] option is very **evil**.
- The use of this [`allowframebreaks`] option is **evil**.

Comment: You are aware that use of this option is considered evil? The only thing I use it for is a list of references, when people have the opportunity to get the references from a copy of the slides later or something like that. (That is, I don't present the references, but they are at the end if people download the slides later.) Other than that, `allowframebreaks` just shouldn't be used.

Comment: The thing is that there are standard ways to avoid things 'dancing', but I doubt they work with `allowframebreaks` because this option isn't at all intended for use with content you are actually going to present on screen.

Comment: @cfr I didn't know that it's evil :). My current situation is not that bad, if that's as good as it gets, then I can live with that. The use case you describe is also one of my use cases, among others.

Comment: It is in the manual: `The use of this option is \emph{evil}.` (page 60)

Comment: Corresponding but report: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/506

Comment: @samcarter Thanks for remembering my question :). I do not fully understand the discussion on github: is the bug fixed or not?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It is only fixed for normal text, not for lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference comes from the following scenario:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}


%\baselineskip0pt
%\lineskip0pt


\vbox{Case1: a vbox}
and then a natural paragraph


\bigskip


\newbox\tempvbox
\setbox\tempvbox=\vbox{and then some vbox content}
\vbox{Case2: a vbox}
\box\tempvbox


\bigskip


\setbox\tempvbox=\vbox{and then some unboxed content}
\vbox{Case3: a vbox}
\unvbox\tempvbox


\end{document}
```

[image]

In the first two cases, the space between lines is determined by `\baselineskip`. By changing `\baselineskip` you can see the space varying.

In the third case, there is basically no space and the two boxes are put side by side. It looks like when both `\baselineskip` and `\lineskip` are zero.

---

Go to beamer. In the definition of the environment `beamer@frameslide`, there is a `\vbox`

> ```
> \vskip-\parskip\vbox{}%
> ```

This corresponds to the `\vbox{Case1`/`2`/`3: a vbox}` above.

Following this `\vbox` is the content of your frame. In this case, there is an `\itemize`. So the first page looks perfect.

Starting from the second page, the content is extracted by the following line

> ```
> \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight%
> ```

and put back to the page by

> ```
> \ifbeamer@slidehaszoom\box\beamer@framebox\else\unvbox\beamer@framebox\fi%
> ```

This corresponds to the third case above. So starting from the second page the space at the top of the page is insufficient.

---

## Appendix

These macros are involved.

### `\beamer@collect@@body`

- `#1` is the content of the frame. That is, anything between `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}`
- `#2` should be the string `frame`. Things will get a little bit tense if you have nested environments.
- `\beamer@envbody` is a tokenlist. According to the fifth line, it will store the content of your frame.

> ```
> \long\def\beamer@collect@@body#1\end#2{%
>   \def\test{#1}%
>   \edef\beamer@begin@stack{\beamer@push@begins#1\begin\end \expandafter\@gobble\beamer@begin@stack}%
>   \ifx\@empty\beamer@begin@stack % This will be true; I do not know what is this for
>       \global\beamer@envbody\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody#1}%
>     \def\reserved@a{#2}
>     \ifx\reserved@a\beamer@frametext%
>       \endgroup%
>       \let\@next=\beamer@process@envbody % A little tricky! Note the grouping
>       \@checkend{#2}%
>     \else%
>       % ok, just expand it, presumably it will generate the desired \end{frame}
>       \let\@next=\beamer@process@expander%
>     \fi
>   \else
>     \global\beamer@envbody\expandafter{\the\beamer@envbody#1\end{#2}}%
>     \let\@next=\beamer@process@envbody%
>   \fi
>   \@next
> }
> ```

### `\beamer@autobreakframe`

After beamer reads `[allowframebreak]`, it will realize how to treat this frame. This macro is what beamer will do next.

After `\begin{beamer@frameslide}`, anything you add will appear at the top of the slide, below the title. (provided that you have a title)

> ```
> \def\beamer@autobreakframe{%
>   \beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
>   \advance\beamer@autobreakcount by1\relax%
>   \begin{beamer@frameslide}\relax%
>     % if you add anything here, it will appear at the top of the slide
>     \bgroup%
>     \aftergroup\beamer@endautobreak%
>     \afterassignment\beamer@checkframetitle%
>     \let\beamer@next% gobble opening brace
>   }
> ```

### `\beamer@endautobreak`

If you add anything before `\end{beamer@frameslide}`, it will appear at the end of the slide. (But it will be too late)

> ```
> \def\beamer@endautobreak{\end{beamer@frameslide}%
>   \beamer@writeslidentry%
>   \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
>     \let\beamer@next=\beamer@reseteecodes%
>   \else%
>     \let\beamer@next=\beamer@continueautobreak%
>   \fi%
>   \beamer@next%
> }
> ```

### `\beamer@autobreakframebox`

This is the algorithm that beamer uses to split looong contents into several pages.

Before this macro, `\beamer@framebox` stores the looong contents. After this macro, `\beamer@splitbox` stores the content that fits a slide/page.

> ```
> \def\beamer@autobreakframebox{%
>   \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
>   \ifbeamer@autobreak%
>     % Ok, frame was overful -> split it!
>     \setbox\@tempboxa=\vsplit\beamer@framebox to\beamer@autobreakfactor\textheight% NOTICE THIS LINE
>     \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\beamer@framebox%
>     \@tempdima=\ht\beamer@splitbox%
>     \ifdim\@tempdima<\beamer@autobreaklastheight%
>       \global\beamer@autobreaklastheight=\@tempdima\relax%
>     \else%
>       \setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\unvbox\@tempboxa\unvbox\beamer@splitbox}%
>       \global\setbox\beamer@splitbox=\box\voidb@x%
>     \fi%
>     \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\@tempboxa%
>       \vskip\beamer@framebottomskipautobreak%
>       \ifvoid\beamer@splitbox%
>         \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
>         \else%
>           \begingroup
>             \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
>             \footnoterule%
>             \unvbox \beamer@footins%
>             \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>           \endgroup  
>         \fi%
>       \fi%
>       \beamer@exitcode%
>     }%
>   \else%
>     \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox to\textheight{\unvbox\beamer@framebox%
>       \vskip\beamer@framebottomskip%
>       \ifvoid\beamer@footins%
>       \else%
>         \begingroup
>           \usebeamercolor*[fg]{footnote}%
>           \footnoterule%
>           \unvbox \beamer@footins%
>           \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>         \endgroup 
>       \fi%
>       \beamer@exitcode}%
>     \global\setbox\beamer@footins=\box\voidb@x%
>   \fi%
>   }
> ```

### `\beamer@continueautobreak`

This is the macro that prints the content to individual slides/pages. Notice the `\unvbox` in the second line from the bottom.

> ```
> \def\beamer@continueautobreak{%
>   \refstepcounter{framenumber}%
>   \expandafter\beamer@frametitletoks\expandafter{\beamer@frametitle}%
>   \expandafter\beamer@framesubtitletoks\expandafter{\beamer@shortframetitle}%
>   \edef\beamer@callframetitle{\noexpand\frametitle[\the\beamer@framesubtitletoks]{\the\beamer@frametitletoks}}%
>   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\beamer@autobreakframe
>   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
>     \expandafter\beamer@callframetitle%
>     \expandafter\framesubtitle\expandafter{\insertframesubtitle}%
>     \unvbox\beamer@splitbox}% NOTICE THIS LINE
> }
> ```

### `beamer@frameslide`

> ```
> \newenvironment{beamer@frameslide}{%
>   \ifbeamer@autobreak\else%
>     \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty%
>       {\let\@elt\beamer@restorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
>     \else%
>       {\let\@elt\beamer@labelrestorecounter\beamer@overlaycounterresets}%
>     \fi%
>   \fi%
>   \global\c@beamerpauses=1\relax%
>   \expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@framestartpage}{%
>     \stepcounter{subsectionslide}%
>     \xdef\beamer@framestartpage{\the\c@page}% only first time
>   }{\clearpage\beamer@notesactions}% cleanup from previous slide
>   \hypersetup{pdfpagetransition=R}%
>   \hypersetup{pdfpageduration=}%
>   \@ifundefined{thispdfpagelabel}{}{%
>   \thispdfpagelabel{\insertframenumber}}%
>   \xdef\beamer@frameendpage{\the\c@page}% every time
>   \beamer@setuplinks%
>   \beamer@displaybreak%
>   \global\setbox\beamer@zoombox=\box\voidb@x%
>   \def\beamer@zoomer{}%
>   \beamer@slidehaszoomfalse%
>   \gdef\insertframetitle{}%
>   \gdef\insertframesubtitle{}%
>   \gdef\beamer@frametitle{}%
>   \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{}%
>   \gdef\beamer@framesubtitle{}%
>   \let\beamer@startcomment=\beamer@startcommentinframe%
>   % Start slide:
>   \beamer@framenotesbegin%
>     \global\setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox\bgroup%
>     \beamer@inframetrue%
>     \let\frame=\framelatex% inside frames, use LaTeX's \frame command
>     \begin{beamer@framepauses}%
>       \refcounter{framenumber}%use frame number for  \label
>       \ifbeamer@shrink%
>         \hsize=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\hsize%
>         \textwidth=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\textwidth%
>         \linewidth=\beamer@shrinkfactorinv\linewidth%
>       \fi%
>       % Insert labels if necessary:
>       \ifx\beamer@againname\@empty\else%
>         \nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss%
>         \label<\the\beamer@slideinframe>{\beamer@againname<\the\beamer@slideinframe>}%
>         \ifnum\beamer@slideinframe=1\relax%
>           \label<1>{\beamer@againname}%
>         \fi%
>         }\nointerlineskip%
>       \fi%
>       \ifx\beamer@framehypertargets\@empty\else%
>         \nointerlineskip\vbox to0pt{\vss%
>           \beamer@framehypertargets%
>           \global\let\beamer@framehypertargets\@empty%
>         }\nointerlineskip%
>       \fi%
>       \vskip-\parskip\vbox{}% NOTICE THIS LINE
>       \ifbeamer@plainframe\nointerlineskip\fi%
>     \beamer@checkframetitle}%
> ```

Before this line is the start of the **frame** (not slide). Notice the third line from the bottom.

After this line is the end of the **frame** (not slide).

> ```
>     {\par
>     \end{beamer@framepauses}%
>   \egroup%
>   \ifx\beamer@frametitle\@empty%
>     \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\box\voidb@x%
>   \else%
>     \setbox\beamer@frametitlebox=\vbox{%
>       \vbox{}%
>       {\parskip0pt\usebeamertemplate***{frametitle}\vskip0.25em}%
>     }%
>   \fi%
>   \ifbeamer@plainframe%
>     \beamer@frametextheight=\paperheight%
>   \else%
>     \beamer@frametextheight=\textheight%
>   \fi%
>   \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\ht\beamer@frametitlebox%
>   \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\dp\beamer@frametitlebox%
>   \advance\beamer@frametextheight by-\beamer@frametopskip%
>   \ifbeamer@shrink%
>     \beamer@shrinkframebox%
>   \fi%
>   \ifx\beamer@zoomer\@empty
>     \setbox\beamer@framebox=\vbox{%
>       \nobreak\vbox{}\nobreak\par\nobreak\beamer@entrycode\nobreak%
>       \nointerlineskip\unvbox\beamer@frametitlebox%
>       \nobreak%
>       \ifbeamer@autobreak%
>         \vskip\beamer@frametopskipautobreak%
>       \else%
>         \vskip\beamer@frametopskip%
>       \fi%
>       \nobreak%
>       \nointerlineskip\box\beamer@zoombox\nointerlineskip%
>       \nobreak%
>       \ifbeamer@slidehaszoom\box\beamer@framebox\else\unvbox\beamer@framebox\fi%
>       % bottom skip is added in autobreakframebox
>     }%
>     \beamer@autobreakframebox%
>   \else%
>     \beamer@zoomer%
>   \fi%
>   \beamer@undolabels%
>   \beamer@framenotesend%
>   \box\beamer@framebox}
> ```

Comment: **First of all, thanks for the effort!** The question did not get a lot of attention so far. I of not understand all of it. What value should i put in my current`\vspace*{\topsep}` space? Amazing how you tracked down the details like `\ifbeamer@slidehaszoom\box\beamer@framebox\else\unvbox\beamer@framebox\fi%`.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It is going to be the value of `\baselineskip` minus the height of the first line of the second page. But since `itemize` add additional vskips at the beginning of the environment, there is no guarantee this will work. You might want to try this with plane text first.

Comment: I tried `\vspace*{\baselineskip}` but it seems that this is not enough, so I think that  `\baselineskip` minus something will not be an solution. I tried both, `\itemize` and normal text (`Text\\ `). I have updated the first code example accordingly.

Comment: I accept your answer since it is amazingly thorough. My problem in not fully solved but at least I have more insight now.

Comment: Since you seem to be an expert here: any idea how to patch beamer, to e.g. not use the `\vskip-\parskip\vbox{}%` in the first place? I'd rather see this problem fixed in beamer itself, than trying to come up with a workaround.