# Beamer bibliography: too much space between title and content

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I am adding the bibliography in the Beamer, and there is too much space between the 'References' and the content. How can I shrink the space in between for all several pages of references? Many thanks in advance!

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{References}
     \printbibliography 
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a short, but compilable test document. If I construct a simple example with the default theme, I can't reproduce this space. https://i.stack.imgur.com/493HU.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I can reproduce a very subtle difference in the spacing between the first and subsequent frames in https://gist.github.com/moewew/787cb659a45a21a47f9856401d0f3c27, but I'm not sure if that is the same issue (probably not - or maybe it is, but just exaggerated somehow).

Comment: @moewe Yes, a tiny bit is expected (mumbling something about lists and framebreaks ... https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/358026/36296 ), but I don't know to to create a gap as big as in the OP. My current theory is a centred frame and the bottom part of the screenshot is cut off... I'd really love to see a reproducible example.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ah, I see. I suspected the unholy numbers of groups `biblatex` introduces to typeset the bibliography (as that is known to create some trouble sometimes), but in any case the problem is much more subtle in any situation I could reproduce than the effect shown here.

Comment: @moewe My crystal ball says that biblatex is not to be blamed :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `t` to the `frame`.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\cite{angenendt}\cite{augustine}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks,t]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]